# Unable to click on drop-down element (uib-dropdown-toggle) using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on Templates from Mail drop-down in below code, I tried all the methods (by_text , by_link, x_path etc..) but the console ends up saying the element/link was not found.
The mail drop-down doesn't have an id or anything related to known methods.

Here's the code i've written

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\vishal 
testing\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://10.20.242.31")

driver.find_element_by_id("login- 
username").send_keys("*******************************")
login = driver.find_element_by_id("login-password")
login.send_keys("**********")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn.btn-default.btn-lg").click()
#select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('MAIL'))
#select.select_by_visible_text('Template')
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('a//[@href="/mail-template"]')
link.click()
```

the code im trying to acess

```
<a href style=color .... ; uib-dropdown-toggle class ="dropdown- 
toggle " aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true'>
<img src = ....><br>"Mail"</a>
<u1 class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu="menu" aria- 
labelledby ="...">
<li role = "menuitems">
<a href="/mail-template"> Templates</a>
</li>
</u1>
```

the console says it was not able to find element named Template or link named /mail-template everytime.

Comment: please add your code trials

Comment: Have you tried this `.dropdown-menu [role='menuitems'] a` css?

Comment: @Dev i have given the code trails, please have a look.thanks.

Comment: @supputuri where shall i put that?  driver.(...)?

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".dropdown-menu [role='menuitems'] a").click()`

Comment: @supputuri thanks, it worked, i had to split in to two steps, first on clicking the dropdown and then in finding the link.

Comment: Cool! Added the answer please accept. Upvote the same if you would like to.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the menu items by using the below locator.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".dropdown-menu [role='menuitems'] a").click()
```

However, make sure you click on the dropdown first to display the menu items, as sometimes the menu items might loaded dynamically.